# Unable to use dialog box more than once in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, fullcalendar

My html coding looks like this:

Main dialog

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialog" title ="Choose" style="display:none">
<form>
    <fieldset align="center">
        <label for="button1"></label>
        <input type="button" name="dialogedit" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="Edit"></button>
        <label for="button2"></label>
        <input type="button" name="dialogdelete" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="Delete"></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Edit Dialog

```
<div id="dialogedit" class="dialogedit" title ="Edit Your Event" style="display:none" align="center">
<form>
    <fieldset align="center">
        <label for="previousEventName">Previous Event:</label>
        <input type="text" name="previousEvent" id="previousEvent" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" readonly>
        <label for="titleEventName">Event Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="titleEvent" id="titleEvent" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" placeholder="Enter your new event">
        <label for="button2"></label>
        <input type="button" name="changeEvent" id="changeEvent" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="Change"></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Delete Dialog

```
<div id="dialogdelete" class="dialogdelete" title ="Delete Your Event" style="display:none" align="center">
<form>
    <fieldset align="center">
        <label for="deleteEventName">Are You Sure?</label><br>
        <input type="button" name="deleteEventYes" id="deleteEventYes" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="Yes!! I Am Sure!"></button>
        <label for="button2"></label><br>
        <input type="button" name="deleteEventNo" id="deleteEventNo" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="No!! Cancel It!"></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My fullcalendar js coding is like this:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                var opt = {
                    autoOpen: false
                };


                $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('[name="dialogedit"]').click(buttonOne);
                        $('[name="dialogdelete"]').click(buttonTwo); 
                    }); 

                        var theDialog = $(".dialog").dialog(opt);
                        var theDialog2 = $(".dialogedit").dialog(opt);
                        var theDialog3 = $(".dialogdelete").dialog(opt);
                        theDialog.dialog("open");

                        function buttonOne(){
                            var cCheck = calEvent.start.toJSON().slice(0,10);
                            var cToday = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
                            if(cCheck < cToday){
                                alert("You are FORBIDED to update an event on past dates");
                            }
                            else{

                                if(theDialog2.dialog("open")){
                                    theDialog.dialog("close");
                                }

                                var previousEvent1 = $("#previousEvent");
                                var newTitleEvent1 = $("#titleEvent");
                                previousEvent1.val(calEvent.title)
                                $("#changeEvent").click(function(){
                                    var newTitleEvent2 = document.getElementById("titleEvent").value;
                                    var oldTitleId = calEvent.id;
                                    console.log(calEvent.title);

                                    var cTitle = JSON.parse(localStorage["events"]);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++) {
                                        if(cTitle[i].id == oldTitleId){
                                            //alert(JSON.stringify(cTitle[i])+"<<<>>>"+oldTitleId);
                                            cTitle[i].title = newTitleEvent2;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }   
                                    localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(cTitle));
                                    calEvent.title = newTitleEvent2;
                                    self.$el.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);


                                    theDialog2.dialog("close");
                                    theDialog2.dialog("destroy");
                                    //alert("Successful");

                                });
                            }   
                        }

                        function buttonTwo(){


                            if(theDialog3.dialog("open")){
                                    theDialog.dialog("close");
                                }
                            $("#deleteEventYes").click(function(e){
                                var deleteId = calEvent.id;

                                e.preventDefault();

                                var items = JSON.parse(localStorage["events"]);
                                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                    if(items[i].id == deleteId){
                                        //alert(JSON.stringify(items[i])+"<<<>>>"+deleteId);
                                        items.splice(i,1);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(items));
                                self.$el.fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent.id);
                                alert("Successful");

                                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");


                            });

                            $("#deleteEventNo").click(function(){
                                theDialog3.dialog("close");
                                theDialog3.dialog("destroy");

                            });

                        }

                    },
```

For my main problem is it seems that i can't do delete more than once, same with edit. Also i can't use both such as delete then edit because all of these will give me some error.

The flow for my dialog is if the user click an event, the main dialog appears which contain `Edit` and `Delete` button. It's user choice either to use which one. I try to do delete first for an event, then edit other event. But then it returns error. I did tried to find the mistake i made somewhere but no luck.

Also i try to close the main dialog after the user has click either `Edit` or `Delete` button. I think it has something wrong on this part. My assumption is that the dialog could have misread my open and close request.

the error i get such as this `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`

please help.

Comment: It doesn't look like a fullcalendar code. please add all the relevant code and even better build a jsFiddle with the code and give us a link to look at

Comment: you sure it doesn't? it's only part of the code. I only want to know if i have some problem with the dialog.

Comment: According to the error you mentioned I guess you do have a problem with the dialog. Actually it is quite self explanatory. But there is no way to debug it that way, you'll have to build some jsFiddle or something similar

Comment: Destroy Dialog box ( div ) after you quit it